Sound crackling in Pop OS 22.04
the sound of my PC keeps crackling, looking online I found this solution
sudo sed -i 's/--\["session.suspend-timeout-seconds"\] = 5/\["session.suspend-timeout-seconds"\] = 0/' /usr/share/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua
systemctl restart --user pipewire.service

On the official Pop OS site, this solution works BUT, I need to do it every time I power my computer, I'm looking for a more permanent solution
Thank you in advance!

/usr/share/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua is a file that should never change during a reboot, so that change that you made using sed should still be there after a reboot. Have you checked the content of that file? it should be setting session.suspend-timeout-seconds to 0 now, without you running the sed command again. Please check and report back!

@MarcusMüller I checked the file and the `session.suspend-timeout-seconds\ is set to 0 after the reboot, But I thought that what made the crackling stop was the restarting  of the pipewire (after rebooting the PC the crackling returns until I ran the command on the post)

but pipewire is inherently "restarted" when you reboot, does that not solve the issue?

@MarcusMüller No, the crackling returns every time I reboot my PC

hmmmmm! I mean,  you sure could add that systemctl restart… to something that's automatically executed by your desktop environment when you log in!

@MarcusMüller I'll do that, Thank you
